# How to implement user permissions in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What I basically want is user permissions.

I've got an table called 'accounts' in my database. There is a column called 'group_id'.
I want to set it when the 'group_id' = 3, then the user is admin. Then he can view special sites, buttons, and things like that. I've tried to implement something like that:

```
public function ($roleName) {
    $role = $this->roles;

    if ($role->name == $roleName) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also, I don't know what and how the model is needed, do I need an new one and things like that.

Comment: I don't really get what you want here. Plus, you do realize your function should have a name, right?

Comment: @Raphael_

yes, I've just copied an quick example how I think it should be done. Also, when a 'group_id' (it's a column in database) is equals to 3, you have administrator previlegies (lets say it's viewing and admins dashboard and things like that).

Comment: So, basically, you have a `users` table and a `groups` table. You're wondering how do you establish a relationship between them?

Comment: @Raphael_
No, I have a table called 'accounts'. In it, there is a column 'group_id'. If a group_id of any account is equals to 3, then he/she can view specific things, (let's say admin dashboard).

Answer (score 6):

Old post, but maybe someone will find this useful

Add a method to your User model that returns true if the user is an admin.  In our case here, it's simply "is our group_id equal to 3?"

```
// models/User.php
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    ... 
    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->group_id == 3;
    }

}
```

Next add a filter that can be used to protect routes

```
// filters.php
Route::filter('admin', function($route, $request)
{
    if ( ! Auth::user()->isAdmin())
    {
        return App::abort(401, 'You are not authorized.');
    }
});
```

Finally use the filter to protect a group of routes.  I this simplified case, only an admin user could access `/admin`

```
// routes.php
Route::group(array('before' => array('auth|admin')), function()
{
    Route::get('/admin', function()
    {
        return Response::make("You're an admin!");
    }
});
```

Based on this post:
http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/admin-route-filter

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [Authority](https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4) for Laravel 4

Comment: By chance do you know of a good tutorial for this package? The documentation on github is weak at best. Does not show how to create Roles or attach permissions to those Roles.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [Verify](http://docs.toddish.co.uk/verify-l4/) package for user management.

Comment: Thanks but I think I don't need that much code. I'm just need one role that can view specific things.

Comment: Ahh I see... I implemented such functionality before. What I did is I created my custom `before` filter that checks that a certain role can access a certain action or the whole controller itself. Maybe you can do the same.

Comment: I know what you mean, but it's all new to me.. any hints of how to do it?